# What is right coding and using useState into Stomp js function? (Websocket)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, stomp

I have a problem with Stomp js. It only renders once. I think the coding is not right. How can you suggest solutions? For example, I have `active` state. But it only renders the initial state. I want to make a Chat app and there are rooms (chat members). When changing room, `active`changes, but when I send messages `active`  does not change into `stompclient`

My codes

```
 const [active, setActive] = useState(null);

 const connect = () => {
    let Sock = new SockJS(socketEndpoint);
    stompClient = over(Sock);
    stompClient.connect({}, onConnected, onError);
  };
  
  console.log(active) // AFTER RENDERING AND SETTING ANOTHER ELEMENT IT CHANGES
  const onConnected = () => {
    stompClient.subscribe(
      "/user/topic/chat/message-result",
      function (order_progress) {
        console.log(active) // AFTER RENDERING AND SETTING ANOTHER ELEMENT IT DOES NOT CHANGE
        let statusData = JSON.parse(order_progress.body);
        if (statusData.status === chatMessageStatus.SUCCESS) {
          if (active === statusData.roomId) {
                    
         ...

 useEffect(() => {
    connect();
    return () => disconnect();
  }, [active]);
```